# How to test a string for containing emoji characters?

Tags: c++, icu

I'm using ICU4C and trying to find the clusters in a UTF-8 string that are emojis. This is the closest I've gotten so far but it incorrectly qualifies the simple character '#' as an emoji (because '#️⃣' begins with '#' and is "potentially" an emoji so '#' does carry the property `UCHAR_EMOJI`).

I think the best would be trying to get the property `RGI_Emoji` as indicated [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/properties.html) but that's a "string" property and not a "codepoint" property and I don't know how to do that. If I could I would analyze every single character as a "string" and test for that string property. The documentation states that, currently, using a regular expression is not possible to get "string" properties.

```
const std::string s8 = "#asd‍dds‍️️‍♂️ds#️⃣ds‍‍‍ds‍❤️‍‍ds";
const icu::UnicodeString us = icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8(s8);
UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
icu::BreakIterator* bi = icu::BreakIterator::createCharacterInstance(icu::Locale::getUS(), status);
bi->setText(us);
bool is_emoji = false;
for(int32_t e = bi->first(), b = e; e != icu::BreakIterator::DONE; b = e, e = bi->next())
{
    // Analyze character for emoji-ness.
    for(int32_t i = b; i != e; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << us.char32At(i) << ' ';
        is_emoji = u_hasBinaryProperty(us.char32At(i), UProperty::UCHAR_EMOJI) || u_hasBinaryProperty(us.char32At(i), UProperty::UCHAR_EMOJI_COMPONENT);
    }
    if(is_emoji)
    {
        std::cout << "<- is emoji\n";
        ++emojis;
        is_emoji = false;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "<- is not emoji\n";
    }
    ++characters;

}
delete bi;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [u_stringHasBinaryProperty](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#ae3201144f35c9cad5ae86bd326b6404a) will give you access to `UCHAR_RGI_EMOJI`. Note that this method is not available in ICU versions < 70.

I think that you need to distinguish between basic emojis that consist of a single code point (e.g. U+1F600 ), and emoji sequences (e.g. U+0023 U+FE0F U+20E3 #️⃣). The [basic emoji](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=1f600&B1=Show) will have both `UCHAR_EMOJI` and `UCHAR_BASIC_EMOJI` properties set and `UCHAR_EMOJI_COMPONENT` unset; the [first code point in a sequence](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0023&B1=Show) will have `UCHAR_EMOJI` and `UCHAR_EMOJI_COMPONENT` set but not `UCHAR_BASIC`. [Subsequent code points](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=fe0f&B1=Show) will have `UCHAR_EMOJI_COMPONENT` set, but not `UCHAR_EMOJI` (nor `UCHAR_BASIC_EMOJI`).

If you encounter '#' (basically any code point with `UCHAR_EMOJI` and `UCHAR_EMOJI_COMPONENT` set) you need to check the next code point. The '#' is part of an emoji only if the next code point doesn't have `UCHAR_EMOJI` but does have `UCHAR_EMOJI_COMPONENT`.